# What role Wifi Password play in the connection with the AP?

Tags: network, ieee-802.11

I was trying to study about how my device connect to the AP via Wifi.

I saw many concepts like WPA,WPA2,MIC, 4 Way Handshake and much more.

I studied all of them but I still cant understand where in all this process my wifi password comes to play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called the *pre-shared key* (PSK) used for authentication in the 802.1X scheme in 802.11 WPA/2/3. Another option is WPA-Enterprise using RADIUS with an authentication server.

Comment: Just to be sure, you mean that my wifi password(lets say 1234) is actually called Pre-Shared-Key and pre-shared it just means that this is the secret between me and my AP? @Zac67

Comment: Yes, pretty much so.